# how to change display none to block when form submits

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp

I am learning JSP, javascript and a little jquery in my own time so please don't mind the probably horrible code or logic but I am making a form and when I submit the form I want it to display 3 labels showing the inputs, as seen in the code below I have it working so far as submitting but I can't seem to figure out how to change the CSS display from none to block. It's probably staring at me in the face but I can't figure it out.

JSP

```
<html>
<body>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/dylan/css/styles.css" />

<form action="form.jsp" id="test" name="test" method="POST">
<label>Please enter your name:</label>
<input name="Name" id="Name">
<br>
<br>
<label>Please enter your number:</label>
<input name="Num" id="Num">
<br>
<br>
<label>Please select your location:</label>
<select name="Location" id="Location">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="UK">UK</option>
  <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
  <option value="France">France</option>
  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>
<button type="button" id="btnsubmit" name="btnsubmit" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<br>

<p><label id="lblName" style="display:none;"><% out.println(request.getParameter("Name")); %></label></p>

<p><label id="lblNumber" style="display:none;"><% out.println(request.getParameter("Num")); %></label></p>

<p><label id="lblLocation" style="display:none;"><% out.println(request.getParameter("Location")); %></label></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/dylan/js/form.js"></script>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the label I am setting the all 3 of the styles to none, I have no idea how to change that to block when submitting the form.

css

```
body {
    background-color:#066;
    color:#fff;
}
form {
    width:400px;
    height:240px;
    Background-color:#000;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:170px;
    Padding:10px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    border-radius:25px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    var mainname, mainnum, mainloc;

    mainname = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    mainnum = document.getElementById("Num").value;
    mainloc = document.getElementById("Location").options[document.getElementById("Location").selectedIndex].value;

    if (mainname == "") {
        alert("Please enter your name");
        return false;
    }

    if (mainnum == "") {
        alert("Please enter your Number");
        return false;
    }

    if (mainloc == '') {
        alert("Please select a country from the list");
        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById("test").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the display to block as below.

```
document.getElementById('lblName').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('lblNumber').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('lblLocation').style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many labels you could use:

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');

for(var i=0; i<labels.length; i++){
    labels[i].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: If you don't know that much you should go and learn javascript better...
after button is clicked ofc